# Is 56 Minutes enough to get between terminals at Newark International (EWR)?

Tags: transit, india, short-connections, new-jersey, north-carolina

I have a flight going from charlotte to Newark, and a 56-minute connection between wheels down in Newark from charlotte, to wheels up in Newark to Mumbai. Could anyone tell me what my odds are on making the flight, and if I cant, what are the odds I will be booked on another flight immediately after? I am flying United and wondered if anyone could tell me where these flights typically land and take off from, like gates and terminals.

Thanks, Josh

Comment: I suppose you have both flights booked on a single ticket? Also, giving us the date and flights (or at least times) would help a lot.

Comment: With up to ten minutes (25 for a big plane) to get out of the plane, and 30 minutes boarding time for the next plane, I bet you are running on the shortest allowed time or well below it.

Comment: Wheels down to wheels up is meaningless.  What you need to know is the amount of time between walking off the jet bridge through the arrival gate and your departure gate closing.  The latter is in my experience usually 10 minutes before the scheduled departure time (which in any event is gate pushback, not takeoff), but knowing the former is pretty much impossible.

Comment: Just to be picky: "wheels up"  and "wheels down" mean literally the time when the aircraft takes off and lands.  The scheduled departure and arrival times usually refer instead to when it leaves and arrives from the gate, and I presume it's those that you are talking about.

Comment: Note that United only seems to have one flight per day from Newark to Mumbai, so even if you are immediately rebooked, you should probably expect that your arrival in Mumbai will be delayed at least 24 hours.  If that's not acceptable then I would suggest changing your itinerary to have a longer connection.

Comment: @NateEldredge more than once I've been on flights announcing that they've arrived on time or early or late mere seconds after landing.  They're not basing that on gate arrival time.

Comment: @phoog: Then I would say they are lying, or at best offering a prediction.

Comment: @NateEldredge apparently you are correct, according to [14 CFR 234.4(f)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/234.4#f).

Comment: @phoog: Interesting, thanks!  I had a sense that this was industry standard procedure, but I didn't know it was prescribed by law / regulation.

Answer (score 1):

**If your flights are on one ticket, United thinks you can easily make it, so don't worry** - after all it is their problem to get you connected, and if you miss your connection, they have to pay for your hotel, transporatation, and food in EWR.
From experience, the international flight will also wait for some connections if they are late.

Rebooking your connection to the next day is not a good plan - you will *for sure* 'miss' your connection on the same day, you will pay extra for the change, and you pay *yourself* for staying a night near EWR. Why pay United money to be allowed to pay for your overnight stay? Let them pay for it, *if* you miss the connection.

If making the connection is important for you (because you don't want to be a day late at the destination), you can call them and ask to get an earlier connection to EWR, there are several daily flights from CLT to EWR.

If you booked it on separate tickets (which I doubt), you should definitely move the first leg earlier, as you and your luggage will never make it - you'd have to go outside of security, and they wouldn't even accept your luggage anymore.

Comment: United will NOT pay for a hotel/etc if the inbound is on time.  If it's late, they will likely only pay if the cause of the delay was their fault (ie, not weather, ATC, etc)